# Azure Machince Learning Pipeline help needed

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I need to create an automated Azure Machine Learning pipeline with Python. I am following a workspace object to create AML object.

Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to Use automated ML in an Azure Machine Learning pipeline in Python
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-automlstep-in-pipelines

A sample notebook with previous data-prep PythonScriptStep plus finally the AutoMLStep (similar scenario than the doc above):
https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/tree/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/nyc-taxi-data-regression-model-building